# Are there any missable trophies and how can we avoid missing them?

Tags: achievements, okami, okami-hd

I've just picked up Okami HD and like any sane person would, I love it. They've added trophies now as well,  which is great. But with this type of game,  especially with a design that's a decade old and never included any meta-game stuff like trophies to begin with,  I'm not sure how easy it will be to get all the trophies in one playthrough. I remember the game being really long, too, so I imagine it would be quite annoying to miss just one!

Are there any trophies that can be accidentally permanently missed in the game, due to things like inaccessible areas, enemies, one-time events,  etc? If so, can we abuse the manual save system to get another chance? Are there certain points where I should create a separate save to be able to access those events/enemies?

I've played the game before but I'm sure plenty of people haven't, so use spoiler tags where appropriate,  please!

Comment: Heh, actually Okami has a _lot_ less missable things than the sequel, Okamiden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PS3Trophies.org's trophy guide & roadmap](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/okami-hd/178562-okami-hd-trophy-guide-roadmap.html) lists 4 missable trophies: **No Furball on the Menu**, **From Imps to Demons**, **Barking Up the Cherry Tree** and **Leave No Chest Unopened**

- **No Furball on the Menu** is only available during a certain part of the game and if you miss it, you must load a previous save.
- **From Imps to Demons** requires you to beat every enemy in the game, one of them is the **Fire Doom Mirror**, which is only available on one mission.
- **Barking Up the Cherry Tree** requires you, among other things, to finish the game with 5 deaths or less. This, of course is missable if you die more than that.
- **Leave No Chest Unopened** requires you to collect all 100 Stray Beads however it was brought to the attention of the Poster of the roadmap that one bead is missable

> Note: It has been brought to my attention that you can miss one Stray Bead, the first one in the game, inside River of the Heavens, when this area closes up. It is pretty hard to not get it though.
>
> > Originally Posted by drkrZEN: 
> >     By the way, it should be noted, for those of you that want to complete this Platinum in one playthrough, that there is one missable Stray Bead not mentioned in the guide. At some point in the game, the entrance to the River of the Heavens closes off. You have ample time to get the Stray Bead there, and even if you miss it, its in the first 10 minutes of a NG+, but its still worth noting.

I recommend you check the trophy guide I linked to and the [individual trophy descriptions](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/okami-hd/178562-okami-hd-trophy-guide-roadmap.html#post3188151) so you know what to look forward to.

Comment: Are you sure about it being missable? Comment #7 here http://www.playstationtrophies.org/game/okami-hd/trophy/55439-Leave-No-Chest-Unopened.html confirms it's not.